# Mathematica wrong about discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

This question is about whether the following function

$$F(a):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}} \log(\left\lvert x \right\rvert ) dx$$
is continuous?

My guess was that this function should be everywhere continuous by the dominated convergence theorem, that is: If $a_n \rightarrow a$ then also $F(a_n )\rightarrow F(a).$

However, Mathematica seems to show that there is a discontiuity roughly at -59. How is that possible? [image: see the Mathematica plot below]

To create this plot, I used the command

```
Plot[NIntegrate[E^(-(x - a)^2/2)*Log[Abs[x]],
                {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}],
     {a, -60, -57}]
```

Comment: It looks like Mathematica's problem (the false value $F(-60) \approx 0$) is with numerical evaluation of an integral, but none of the points where the integrand was evaluated is close to $-60$.  In Maple I can get this erroneous value $\approx 0$ and the correct value $\approx 10$ by evaluating the numerical integral in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your integral into $\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\infty$ and substitute $x:=-x'$ in the first integral. You then obtain
$$F(a)=2e^{-a^2/2}\int_0^\infty \cosh(ax)\>e^{-x^2/2}\>\log x\>dx\ ,$$
whereby the resulting integral has a mild singularity at $x=0$. Writing $\cosh(ax)=1+2\sin^2{ax\over2}$ you can move this singularity into a first integral which does not depend on $a$:
$$F(a)=2e^{-a^2/2}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\>\log x\>dx+2\int_0^\infty\bigl(\sinh^2{ax\over2}\log x\bigr)\>e^{-x^2/2}\>dx\right)\ .$$
 The function $F$ turns out to be an even function of $a$ which is as smooth as you like.